# If 3 colours are used for a plane there exists a length 1 segment with edges of same colour.

Tags: plane-geometry, coloring

A secondary school problem:
*Prove that for any colouring of a plane with three colours there exists a segment of length 1 with edges of same colour.*

My attempt to prove. Take any point A on the plane and let it have colour 1. Draw a circle of radius 1 with the centre at A, where all points on the circumference must have a colour  different from 1, otherwise the segment is found. Take a regular hexagon inscribed into the circle. Its sides have length 1 and the vertices have colours 2 and 3, while no adjacent vertices must have same colour. So vertices $B_1$, $B_3$, $B_5$ have colour 2, vertices $B_2$, $B_4$, $B_6$ have colour 3 and no contradiction!

I tried spreading the triangles making a triangular grid covering the plane. It doesn't help either, as any time the colour for a new vertex can be found.

Comment: Yes, the triangular grid has a 3-colouring, so you will have to leave that grid to prove the statement. Spoiler: [Moser Spindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser_spindle)

Comment: Do you mean *vertices* of the same colour?

Comment: Gonçalo. I mean end points of a segment.